# Detect when a user logged in or out

Tags: slack-api, slack

I need to know how to detect when a user has logged in or out in a team in Slack.

I'm building my first Slack app that consists of storing user's status in the database, and I need a guidance to know how to detect when a user logged in and out, to automatically change their status.

I'm developing with Node.js and hosting it on Heroku.

**Edit**

I've installed `@slack/client` module and this is how I tried to manage when a user logs in or out:

```
rtm.start();
rtm.on(RTM_EVENTS.PRESENCE_CHANGE, function(x) {
    db.users.insert({
        userid: x.user,
        status: x.presence === 'active' ? 'HERE' : 'OFF'
    });
});
```

But it doesn't detect when I close the browser tab, just when I stay idle for 30 minutes and when I refresh the page or log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll see the [`presence_change`](https://api.slack.com/events/presence_change) event via the RTM API. Someone will be set to "away" when they log out (or manually set themselves to away) and "active" when they log in (or manually set themselves back to active).

**EDIT**

Here's my code:

```
var RtmClient = require('@slack/client').RtmClient;
var RTM_EVENTS = require('@slack/client').RTM_EVENTS;

var token = '<REDACTED>';

var rtm = new RtmClient(token);

rtm.on(RTM_EVENTS.PRESENCE_CHANGE, function (event) {
    console.log(event.user + ': ' + event.presence);
});

rtm.start();
```

And the output when I opened a tab to that Slack team and then closed it:

```
U11C8V57T: active
U11C8V57T: away
```

Comment: Cool, that seems to be it, but it also seems it doesn't know when the user has closed the browser tab, only when he has entered.

Comment: Are you saying you don't see an event when a user leaves by closing a browser tab?

Comment: Yes, I've tried `channel_leave`, `channel_left`, `group_left` but none of these detected when I logged off of close the tab to execute a method for updating the status.

Comment: It's working fine for me. If I connect a bot to the RTM API, I see a `presence_change` event when I open a tab to that Slack team in the browser, and I see another `presence_change` event when I close the tab. If you're still seeing issues, maybe you can provide more details about what you're doing.

Comment: I get it now. I'm using this event only when a user logs in, setting his status to 'HERE'. So it also is used for when an user has logged out.

Comment: When I closed the tab I did not receive any event change, not even when I log out, @smarx

Comment: I've edited my question adding the piece of code I use the `presence_change` event.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. I'm adding code and output to my answer, but I essentially used the same code as you.

Comment: One thing to double check: are you logged in elsewhere? (Another computer, a phone, another browser, the desktop app, etc.) Maybe you're only logging out from one place, so you're still online.

Comment: I've changed the e-mail I've logged in to test and now it does how `away` when I close the tab. Weird, because I logged off the app in my Android.